# Crystal Reports, Suppressing a page based on null value

Tags: crystal-reports

Anyone know if there is a way of changing the 'Enabled' property of a Crystal Reports page based on a formula?  For example, I have multiple pages in a report. When the filter for a data band on said page returns a null value, the page appears blank, and is printed as a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

There's options at the details, group header/footer, page header/footer, and report header/footer sections to "Suppress Bank Section". Find the one that's right for you:

[image]